# CSS: How to stop LI widening in drop down menu

Tags: html, css

I have a relativelly well working drop down menu for what I want, but there's one unintended bug that I'm not sure how to resolve. Consider this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pzae/). The bug is most obvious when you hover over **{A}**. Because the nest `UL` has lots of elements it widens to the right, but the parent `LI` also widens to fit it, which makes its nested `A` fill the width, which makes the UI expand and contract. How can I keep the parent `LI` from expanding to the width of the nested `UL`? The other nested `UL`s don't show the bug, but that's only because their nested `LI`s are empty.

Comment: Set the width of the parent LI to a specific value. Otherwise, the browser is doing what it is supposed to.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman, setting the parent `LI`s width causes the nested `UL` to constrain its width, which causes the nested `LI`s in it to shift from row order to column order. That's not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

is this a static list?

if so just add a class to the

```
<a class="Afixded">{A} ▾</a>
```

and then goes into the css

```
li a.Afixded{width:40px;}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pzae/2/)

Comment: this almost works, but look at the very left `LI` with the smiley face. The `UL` still expanding the parent `LI`. Same thing is happening with the **{A}**, but since there's nothing after it you don't see it.

Comment: Add another class to it if your List is static contents there is no harm having a few extra css classes